# is There Any Way To set Imageview As Backgroung and Button and Text Show On That ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

hello Friends I want To set Image View As In Background And My Button and Text View Show On That Image ..
i want my Image View in Background And Cover All Screen Like Background ..and Button And Image View Will Show on that image view please help i am new thanks for help in advance
i m using `ImageLoader.class`to get Image from Url

here is My Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sendmessage"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:visibility="gone"/> -->



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/anim"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/anim"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_msg" 
   android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/anim"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_favorit"
    android:text=""
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addfrnd"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_frndreq"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/anim"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/anim_button"
    android:text="animation" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/loader" />
```

My ImageLoader Class

```
public class ImageLoader {

// the simplest in-memory cache implementation. This should be replaced with
// something like SoftReference or BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

private File cacheDir;

static ArrayList<String> img_path = new ArrayList<String>();

static String sd_card_folder_name = "ImageLoader";

static int width;
Context mContext;

public ImageLoader(Context context, Activity acc) {
    mContext = context;
    // Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect
    // the UI performance
    photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    acc.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    Log.d("width", "width = " + width);

    cache.clear();

    img_path = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(), sd_card_folder_name);
    else
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    if (!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();

}

final int stub_id = R.drawable.loader;

public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) {
    try {
        String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());

        File[] file_array = cacheDir.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < file_array.length; i++) {
            img_path.add(file_array[i].getName());
        }

        if (img_path.contains(filename)) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/" + sd_card_folder_name + "/"
                            + filename));
        } else {
            if (cache.containsKey(url)) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
            } else {
                queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView, filename);
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView, String _name) {
    // This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be
    // some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them.
    photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView, _name);
    synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
        photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
        photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
    }

    // start thread if it's not started yet
    if (photoLoaderThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
        photoLoaderThread.start();
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    // I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the
    // demo.

    if (url != null && !(url.equals(""))) {
        String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);

        /*
         * // from SD cache Bitmap b = decodeFile(f); if (b != null) return
         * b;
         */
        // from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
         final int REQUIRED_SIZE=300;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }
        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

// Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public String _name;

    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i, String n) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
        _name = n;
    }
}

PhotosQueue photosQueue = new PhotosQueue();

public void stopThread() {
    photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
}

// stores list of photos to download
class PhotosQueue {
    private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad = new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

    // removes all instances of this ImageView
    public void Clean(ImageView image) {
        for (int j = 0; j < photosToLoad.size();) {
            if (photosToLoad.get(j).imageView == image)
                photosToLoad.remove(j);
            else
                ++j;
        }
    }
}

class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                // thread waits until there are any images to load in the
                // queue
                if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() == 0)
                    synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
                        photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                    }
                if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() != 0) {
                    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                    synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
                        photoToLoad = photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                    }
                    Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                    cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                    Object tag = photoToLoad.imageView.getTag();
                    String FileName = photoToLoad._name;
                    if (FileName != null
                            && ((String) FileName).equals(photoToLoad._name)) {
                        BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp,
                                photoToLoad.imageView, FileName);
                        Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView
                                .getContext();
                        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                    }
                }
                if (Thread.interrupted())
                    break;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // allow thread to exit
        }
    }
}

PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread = new PhotosLoader();

// Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView imageView;
    String file_name;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i, String _name) {
        bitmap = b;
        imageView = i;
        file_name = _name;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (bitmap != null) {

            load_full_image(imageView, file_name, bitmap);

        } else
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private Runnable mMyRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
};

public void load_full_image(ImageView img, String _name, Bitmap btmp) {
    img_path = new ArrayList<String>();

    File[] file_array = cacheDir.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < file_array.length; i++) {
        img_path.add(file_array[i].getName());
    }

    if (img_path.contains(_name)) {
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),BitmapFactory
                            .decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/" + sd_card_folder_name + "/"
                                    + _name));
         img.setBackground(d);
    } else {

        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),btmp);

        img.setBackground(d);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    // clear memory cache
    cache.clear();

    // clear SD cache
    File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
    for (File f : files)
        f.delete();
}
```

My Activyt Class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.userprofile);
Button addfrnd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addfrnd);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
UserModel user = (UserModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("User");
 UserByIdModel tempuser = (UserByIdModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("UserById");
String UserId=String.valueOf(tempuser.getUser_Id());
String image_url=tempuser.getUser_Image();
int loader = R.drawable.loader;
ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext(),
        UserByIdProfile.this);
//
image.setTag(image_url);

  // whenever you want to load an image from url
 // call DisplayImage function
 // url - image url to load
// loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
 // image - ImageView 
imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, UserByIdProfile.this, image);
```

Comment: set background for releative layout then it will work i.e, android:background="@drawable/drawable_name"

Comment: @android_dev Can You Explain Me With Ur Answer please

Comment: I m getting Image From Url As Imageview ..How To Set That Image As Background image

Comment: how about using ImageButton class?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood everything, but IMO you should try to set an image as background of your RelativeLayout, because for now your ImageView is the last drawn, so it will appears on top of everything

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/loader" >
```

Then add everything in that RelativeLayout,just like you did ;)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sir i m getting Image From Url as Imagview ...Loader Image is Loading Image When There Is no Image from Image Loader will Show

Comment: In that case, use the drawable you get from that URL and use it to modify the background of your RelativeLayout, using 
    yourRelativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(yourDrawable);

Comment: Sir How To Use drawable

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/your_image_name"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/anim"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/anim"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_msg" 
   android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/anim"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_favorit"
    android:text=""
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addfrnd"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_frndreq"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/anim"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/anim_button"
    android:text="animation" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/loader" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Try This For dynamically

```
public void changeBackground(RelativeLayout relativeLayout, BitmapDrawable drawable){
        relativeLayout.setBackground(drawable);
}
```

Comment: android_dev I want to set that image as background ...Which i m Getting At ImageView

Comment: You wants to set dynamically?

Comment: After getting image from url convert that image to BitmapDrawble and pass it to above method it will work i will update the above response

Comment: Sir I m Using ImageLoader class ...I m New on android ..How To Convert That BitmapDrawable ..

i m Updated my ImageLoader .Class And ..Actvity Class

Answer (score 0):

```
//To download an image and set it as content for an imageview

try {
  ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
  i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Make Sure you have internet permission in Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Try to call using AsyncTask because we are doing Network Operations

If you want to set the RelativeLayout Programmatically that get its id. and `setBackgroundResource(yourImage)`

Views you want to show with a single Background . Put them in a RelativeLayout and set the  `android:background="@drawable/SingleBgImageForViewsInsideRelativeLayout"`

Comment: Sir I Load image From url using ImageLoader Class how to set that Image as background to perticular activity